# Do I need a transit visa for a layover in Kochi (Cochin) airport?

Tags: india, transit-visas, malaysian-citizens, airasia, spicejet

I will be flying from Kuala Lumpur to Dubai, UAE via Kochi.

As the airline service providers are different when I transit in Kochi, I have been advised that I will need to pick up my bags in Kochi airport and then recheck my bags to board the connecting flight (as the airlines will not transfer my bags automatically). This means that I may need to go through immigration in order to collect my baggage.

Given the situation above, can someone please confirm if I need a transit visa in Kochi?

For additional information, the followings are my flight details:

KUL - COK arriving at Kochi airport Terminal 3 at 20:10 with AirAsia. 
COK - DXB departing from Kochi airport Terminal at 23:45 (same day) with Spicejet.

My nationality is Malaysian and I have a resident visa of the UAE.

Comment: Is it a disjoint itinerary?

Comment: On the first sight I thought you were transiting at a small remote airport in Japan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dchi_Airport). I was thinking: they have international flights...?

Answer (score 3):

As you'll have to go through customs you should get an e-visa.

As a Malaysian Citizen you can get one and it's valid at Kochi Airport.

[Citizenships that can apply for an e-visa](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html):

> Albania, Andorra, Angola, Anguilla, Antigua & Barbuda, Argentina,
>   Armenia, Aruba, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Bahamas, Barbados,
>   Belgium, Belize, Bolivia, Bosnia & Herzegovina, Botswana, Brazil,
>   Brunei, Bulgaria, Burundi, Cambodia, Cameron Union Republic, Canada,
>   Cape Verde, Cayman Island, Chile, China, China- SAR Hongkong, China-
>   SAR Macau, Colombia, Comoros, Cook Islands, Costa Rica, Cote d'lvoire,
>   Croatia, Cuba, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Djibouti, Dominica,
>   Dominican Republic, East Timor, Ecuador, El Salvador, Eritrea,
>   Estonia, Fiji, Finland, France, Gabon, Gambia, Georgia, Germany,
>   Ghana, Greece, Grenada, Guatemala, Guinea, Guyana, Haiti, Honduras,
>   Hungary, Iceland, Indonesia, Iran, Ireland, Israel, Italy, Jamaica,
>   Japan, Jordan, Kazakhstan, Kenya, Kiribati,Kyrgyzstan , Laos, Latvia,
>   Lesotho, Liberia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Madagascar,
>   Malawi, **Malaysia**, Mali, Malta, Marshall Islands, Mauritius,
>   Mexico, Micronesia, Moldova, Monaco, Mongolia, Montenegro, Montserrat,
>   Mozambique, Myanmar, Namibia, Nauru, Netherlands, New Zealand,
>   Nicaragua, Niger Republic, Niue Island, Norway, Oman, Palau,
>   Palestine, Panama, Papua New Guinea, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines,
>   Poland, Portugal , Republic of Korea, Republic of Macedonia, Romania,
>   Russia, Rwanda, Saint Christopher and Nevis, Saint Lucia, Saint
>   Vincent & the Grenadines, Samoa, San Marino, Senegal, Serbia,
>   Seychelles, Sierra Leone, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, Solomon
>   Islands, South Africa, Spain, Sri Lanka, Suriname, Swaziland, Sweden,
>   Switzerland, Taiwan, Tajikistan, Tanzania, Thailand, Tonga, Trinidad &
>   Tobago, Turks & Caicos Island, Tuvalu, UAE, Uganda,Ukraine, United
>   Kingdom, Uruguay, USA, Uzbekistan, Vanuatu, Vatican City-Holy See,
>   Venezuela, Vietnam, Zambia and Zimbabwe

[Airports where the e-visa is accepted](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html):

e-Visa is valid for entry through 25 designated Airports, i.e.

> Ahmedabad, Amritsar, Bagdogra, Bengaluru, Calicut, Chennai,
>   Chandigarh, **Cochin**, Coimbatore, Delhi, Gaya, Goa, Guwahati,
>   Hyderabad, Jaipur, Kolkata, Lucknow, Mangalore, Mumbai, Nagpur, Pune,
>   Tiruchirapalli, Trivandrum, Varanasi & Vishakhapatnam

However, the foreigner can take exit from any of the authorized Immigration Check Posts (ICPs) in India.